# passing $MyInvocation.UnBoundArguments to a nested function in Powershell

Tags: powershell

I want a function to pass all of it arguments to another function.  Is there a better way of doing this?  My version doesn't seem to work right however.

```
function remote {
    $fargs = $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments

    remote_version1 @fargs      
}

function remote_version1 {
param(
    [alias("m", "computer")]    
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [string]$Machine  = "",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [string]$loc_file = "",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [string]$rem_file = "",
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [switch]$tmp,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [switch]$banner,
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [int]$profile     = $script:remote_profile,  
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$false)]   [int]$Hop         = $script:remote_hop        # Second Hop Mode     
)
    #write-host $MyInvocation.BoundParameters   
    write-host "loc_file: $loc_file"
    write-host "rem_file: ($rem_file)"
}

$common_flags              = @{}
$common_flags["Banner"]    = $true
$common_flags["Machine"]   = "mymachine"
$common_flags["Hop"]       = $true
$common_flags["Profile"]   = $true
remote @common_flag -loc_file .\file.txt  -tmp
```

Result:

```
loc_file: .\file.txt
rem_file: True   ##<==== Why True?  SHould be "" since 
                 ##      it isn't set when called??
```

(I can't seem to reproduce the output by snipping the code out of script.. makes me think powershell has some type of pointer bug?
But this is the problem i'm having... $rem_file is set
to a boolean for some reason, when its a string...)

Maybe i'm passing the wrong type into the "splat operator" @, and the orderingof items is random in the hash?  but powershell doesn't seem to complain its the wrong object type?

Is there a way to convert a string into a company and execute it instead of using splat?

Comment: If you can't reproduce the problem, how can you still have the problem? To pass _all_ arguments, do `targetCommand @PSBoundParameters @args`

Comment: I don't know, sorry, I just found a work around using invoke-expression instead.

Comment: I don't *think* this has anything to do with your issue but, in powershell, when an optional string parameter is not passed to a function its value is always "" - so explicitly defining an empty string as a fallback is redundant.

Comment: Are you explicitly naming every parameter when providing them as arguments to the remote function? If not I would try that. It sounds like the string is being cast to a bool - which means powershell is probably trying to deduce what the parameters are purely from their order in the list and assuming its one of the switch params.

Answer (score 2):

The [automatic `$args` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#args) has built-in magic when used for [splatting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Splatting) (`@args`), allowing it to pass *named* arguments through properly - note that this does *not* work with any other arrays, whether self-created array or returned from  `$MyInvocation.UnboundArguments`.

Therefore, the following should meet your needs:

```sh
function remote {
  # @args passes both named and positional (unnamed) arguments through.
  remote_version1 @args      
}
```

Note:

- If the relaying function (`remote`) itself had declared parameters (with a `param(...)` block), you could also relay *them* with `@PSBoundParameters`, via [automatic `$PSBoundParameters` variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Automatic_Variables#psboundparameters).
- If a relaying function with declared parameters is *non-advanced*, you may use `@PSBoundParameters` in *addition* to passing unbound arguments through with `@args`, whereas [*advanced functions*](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_Functions_Advanced) by definition prevent passing unbound arguments (in other words: they do not support `$args`).

Comment: very useful knowledge! Until now I thought splatting always had to be used w/ a previously explicitly declared hashtable of params

Comment: Glad to hear it, @diopside. _Any variable_ - whether automatic (built in) or user-defined - can be used for splatting, by prefixing its name with `@` instead of `$`: If it contains an array or array-like collection, each element is passed as a _positional_ (unnamed) argument. If it contains a hashtable or hashtable-like data structure (a type that implements `[System.Collections.IDictionary]`), each entry is passed as a _named_ argument, where the entry's _key_ names the target parameter (without the leading `-`), and the _value_ is its argument. A scalar (single) value is passed as-is.

Answer (score -2):

UnboundArguments is an Array instead of a Hash.  I simply print the Array to convert it to a string and feed it to invoke-expression.

```
        $fargs = $MyInvocation.UnboundArguments
        $fargs = $fargs -replace "True", "`$true"
        $fargs = $fargs -replace "False", "`$false"
        invoke-expression  "remote_version1 $fargs"
```

Comment: The obligatory warning: `Invoke-Expression`  (`iex`) should generally be _avoided_ and used only as a _last resort_, due to its inherent security risks. Superior alternatives are usually available. If there truly is no alternative, only ever use it on input you either provided yourself or fully trust - see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51252636/45375).

Comment: Security risks aside, your solution has severe limitations, such as not being able to relay arguments with embedded spaces or arguments with types other than strings or numbers.